# Find files in multiple directories taken from list in a file?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, find, freebsd

```
FreeBSD 9.2 RELEASE p2
```

I have a file `fromdirs.txt`. In this file is a new line separated directory list like so:

```
/etc
/home
/home/goods/
```

I need to first find in all directory's files which have names like "good" or contain string "(NODES_'TASK')" and then copy all these files into the directory `/tmp`.

2.sh file chmod +x and is 755
fromDirs.txt file chmod +x and is 755

This code give me error

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a dirs < fromDirs.txt
find "${dirs[@]}" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "(NODES_'TASK')" {} \; \) -exec cp {} /tmp/ \;
```

**2.sh: cannot open fromDirs.txt : No such file or directory**

**2.sh: ${dirs[...}: Bad substitution**

But File fromDirs.txt exist and 2.sh running from it allocation directory, also i trying to provide full path instead of fromDirs.txt and error the same

This code give me error

```
FILE=fromDirs.txt
IFS='\n'
while read -r dirs
do
find "$dirs" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "(NODES_'TASK')" {} \; \) -exec cp {} /tmp/ \;
done < "$FILE"
```

**2.sh: 6: Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")**

This code give me error too

```
FILENAME=fromDirs.txt

awk '{kount++;print  kount, $0}
     END{print "\nTotal " kount " lines read"}' $FILENAME
```

**2.sh: : not found awk: can't open file fromDirs.txt source line number 2**

So how to read file line by line and do what i need?

Comment: Try it with `bash`, instead of `sh`

Comment: try with `ksh`, or dbl-check your PATH environment. I have no experience with FreeBSD, but hard to imagine `bash` or `ksh` not being available. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
 for line in "`cat fromDirs.txt`"; do find "$line" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "(NODES_'TASK')" {} \; \) -exec cp {} /tmp/ \;; done
```