# Linux cp with full paths

Tags: linux, copy, concatenation, cp

How to copy file to dir with full file destination path?

When i use:

```
cp --parents /etc/passwd /tmp
```

I get an error

```
cp: illegal option -- - usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-f | -i | -n] [-alpvx] source_file target_file cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-f | -i | -n] [-alpvx] source_file ... target_directory
```

And if i using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821119/find-files-in-multiple-directories-taken-from-list-in-a-file)

```
for line in "`cat fromDirs.txt`"; do find "$line" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "(NODES_'TASK')" {} \; \) -exec cp {} /tmp/ \;; done
```

maybe there are possibility to concatenate the variables like

```
-exec cp $line{} /tmp/ \;; done
or
-exec cp {} /tmp/$line \;; done
```

???

Comment: The first command (`cp --parents /etc/passwd /tmp`) works fine for me.  What implementation / version of `cp` are you using?

Comment: I dont khow! how to check that?

Comment: Try `cp --version` or see `man cp`.  Mine is `cp (GNU coreutils) 8.22`.

Comment: **cp --version**
`cp: illegal option -- - usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-f | -i | -n] [-alpvx] source_file target_file cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-f | -i | -n] [-alpvx] source_file ... target_directory`

**man cp**
`CP(1) FreeBSD General Commands Manual CP(1)`

Comment: Well, then, at least, it is not the GNU one.  You'll need to find the manual for your version of `cp`.  As it seems, yours does not accept any long options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your version of `cp` does not accept long options.  When it sees `--parents` it thinks you are trying to use the `-` option (as well as the `p`, `a`, `r`, etc. options).

You can emulate it like this:

```
source=/etc/passwd
mkdir -p /tmp/$(dirname $source)
cp $source /tmp/$source
```

Comment: ok what i can do in this place? How to concatenate then? and how to change my script to look like you say?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin: I edited my answer to add some code you can try.