# Find`s placeholder {} sed from variable1 and put into variable2

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

Then i use this script

```
for line in "`cat fromDirs.txt`"; 
do 
   find "$line" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "(NODES_'TASK')" {} \; \) -exec cp {} /tmp/ \;; 
done
```

I get in folder /tmp only file names from where they are copied, but i need this filenames contains full paths from where they comes, im bored to trying fight with sed, please help

So i need just take each {} value and replace slash (/) with minus sign (-)

I trying many of variant but nothing good, this code do not work too

```
for line in "`cat fromDirs.txt`"; 
do 
   find "$line" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "(NODES_'TASK')" {} \; \) -exec cp {} /tmp/$(sed "s/\//-/g" <<< {}) \;;
done
```

file fromDirs.txt contains

```
/home/orders/
/etc/bin/school/
```

there are no output, just nothing haping, maybe beacause i use sh? i havent bash at all on system

I think the problem is in sed as it read placeholder {} as file instead of string, so if {} = /home/orders/good.php then sed open this file and change all slashes to minus sign, but i need to changeslashes only in filename so `/home/orders/good.php -> -home-orders-good.php` and then cp to `/tmp/-home-orders-good.php`

Comment: Can you give a sample input file and Expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you get problem since you double quote the output of the file.
Try change from:

```
for line in "`cat fromDirs.txt`";
```

to:

```
for line in `cat fromDirs.txt`;
```

or better (remove old and outdated back tics):

```
for line in $(cat fromDirs.txt);
```

best (use while to read the file):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
   find "$line" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "(NODES_'TASK')" {} \; \) -exec cp {} /tmp/$(sed "s/\//-/g" <<< {}) \;;
done < fromDirs.txt
```

Comment: for line in `cat fromDirs.txt`; for line in $(cat fromDirs.txt); does not work too (just nothing happing), third variant do not for for me at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821119/find-files-in-multiple-directories-taken-from-list-in-a-file

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin what do you get from `echo $(cat fromDirs.txt)`

Comment: contents of fromDirs.txt
`/home/orders/
/etc/bin/school/`